# How can I compile C code containing <gmp.h> with mpicc?

Tags: c, mpi, gmp

I just installed gmp from https://gmplib.org/, on my MacBook, which I'm completely new to. (I'm quite new to C and mpi as well for that matter.)

Now I have a C code containing both the headers mpi.h and gmp.h. If I try to compile the code with mpicc, as I usually do when not using gmp, it complains about not finding 'gmp.h'. On the other hand, if I compile with gcc it complains about not finding 'mpi.h'. So, what should I do to be able to compile my code?

I need both the headers since I will need to work with huge numbers in a parallel environment. I.e. removing any one of them is really not an option.

I'm thankful for any help with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the path to `gmp.h` in your arguments to `mpicc`?

Comment: I don't know with mpicc, but with `gcc` you must use `-I` oprion to add path of headers. If those headers are not into environment path.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion JAB. It helped indirectly. While looking for the folder where gmp.h was to be installed I found out it was not where mpicc was looking for it. (Strange though that gcc didn't complain.) So I reinstalled it into /usr/local/include and now it compiles as it should.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Given that you're new to C, debugging `gmp` can be a challenge, and using `MPI` is another challenge. Getting `gmp` to work over `MPI` is yet another. I might split it up a bit: do some `gmp` stuff and `MPI` stuff independently before working on the combined project. Validating your `gmp` against ordinary straight C in a unit test. That way, you're sure of your `gmp` code _before_ adding `MPI` to the mix. This way, you're only taking one risk at a time instead of three all at once.

Comment: `mpicc` is nothing more than a wrapper, which supplies some C compiler with additional arguments related finding and linking the MPI library. Consequently, it is used the same way as the C compiler and accepts the same arguments. `mpicc --show` or `mpicc --showme` shows which compiler is called behind the scenes.

Comment: @Craig Estey. Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely try to isolate each subproblem to minimize the risk. Besides I'm writing a slow sequential, somewhat stripped down, version of the project in Matlab which helps to test some aspects of the code.